# Convert depth index of Data3Texture to z-coordinate of NDC

Tags: three.js, clipping, 3d-texture, shadermaterial

I want to clip a Data3DTexture (with width, height, depth) at a specific depth, so only render at this depth position and hide all other layers.

I adapt the clipping method from this idea ([text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065267/clipping-a-volume-in-three-js-giving-black-area-instead-of-inner-material) ) to VolumeShader provided in ThreeJs.

The volume shader code to change: [text](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/shaders/VolumeShader.js)

So I compute the color, only at this depth.
In cast_mip functions ( and cast_iso ), break the loop for all points outside this depth. As following:

if (loc.z < a_depth_index  )
break;

a_depth_index: in [0, depth]

The problem is loc.z is in NDC coordinante, so [0, -1].

How can I convert a depth index of Data3DTexture to NDC z-coordinate, please ?

I saw this post [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031802/referencing-texels-in-a-data-texture-using-indexes-in-the-shader). But it seems to be good for 2D, not for 3D neither depth position.

Thank you for any help.